# getting bundle error when trying to load svg with raw-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My goal is to read in an svg as a raw string using raw-loader, then use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to add this svg string to a div and thus render the svg. However, I am running into an issue when importing the svgs. I get receive the following cryptic error in the console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string". The error seems to be coming from bundle.js. When I click on it to find out more, the line it highlights is

```
/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = (undefined"<svg width=\"36\" height=\"36\" viewBox=\"0 0 40 30\" fill=\"none\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">\n  <path d=\"M2 1V14.0263L29.3553 16.1974L2 18.3684V31.3947L35 16.1974L2 1Z\" fill=\"#2996CC\"/>\n  <path d=\"M2 1V14.0263L29.3553 16.1974L2 18.3684V31.3947L35 16.1974L2 1Z\" stroke=\"#2996CC\" stroke-width=\"0.434211\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\"/></svg>");
```

Because I am using webpack (version `4.39.2`), I had to write a rule to import svgs. The rule I am using is:

```
{ test: /\.svg$/, loader: "raw-loader" },
```

And then in the .jsx files (I am using reactjs), I use

```
import sendIcon from "./SVGs/Plane.svg";
```

The actual div then looks something like

```
<div
    className="RefreshIcon"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: planeIcon }}
/>
```

Interestingly, if I run `rm -rf node_modules` before compiling then everything is fine. However, this seems very hacky and I would like to avoid that solution if at all possible. I include it only because it may lend insight into what the main problem is.

I expect to see the svgs displayed correctly, but instead the whole screen is clear except for the text "loading" and I get the aforementioned error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this turned out to be an issue with webpack itself - the version of webpack I was using had some kind of caching issue as described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8052) 
I rolled back to version 4.19 and this resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Svg should be use with file-loader

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
```

You can view my full config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I load the svg into my code (i.e. what replaces the dangerouslyLoadHTML part)?